# Rails 3.2.6 DEPRECATION WARNING: :confirm option is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 4.0. Use ':data => { :confirm => 'Text' }0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, warnings, deprecated

This is a warning that began to appear after I upgraded my app from Rails 3.2.3 to 3.2.6.  Here is the line of code in my "datatables" related class that it is pointing to:

```
class PdpsDatatable
  delegate :current_user, :is_reader?, :is_admin?, :is_user?, :show_num, :params, :h, :link_to, to: :@view
  # the line above is what the warning is pointing to
end
```

Is there any easy fix to this warning?  It is just plain annoying.

thanks.

Bharat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is not in this line.... You probably have the `:confirm` in somewhere else in your application, such as `button_to`, `button_tag`, `image_submit_tag`, `link_to`, or `submit_tag`.

More details about this deprecation [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/fc092a9cba5fceec38358072e50e09250cf58840).

A possible solution for this warning [here](http://ariejan.net/2012/06/18/search-and-replace-in-multiple-files-with-vim).

Comment: this was indeed in the link_to function.  thanks for the pointer.

Comment: In my case (rails `3.2.7`) the deprecation warnings were accurately pointing to the exact lines in my `index` views with `link_to`s with `confirm: 'Are you sure?'` (incidentally, all were `method: :delete`). Indeed, replacing with `:data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }` did the trick.